# what should be done on questions where low rep users have answered in question text?

Tags: discussion, new-users, close-reasons, self-answer

I suppose this is an extension to [Comments incorrectly submitted as an answer instead: what should we do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/comments-incorrectly-submitted-as-an-answer-instead-what-should-we-do)

<strike>First off, I'm presuming that new users cannot answer their own questions? Is this correct?</strike>

**So they can self answer**, but I've seen quite a few occasions where they don't!

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3389954) the user, has edited the question to include an answer. I've seen this quite a lot. I've always flagged this as

> Unclear what your asking

For me, the user editing the question in this manner invalidates the question. Is this the correct thing to do?

Could/should we make the answer my own question link more obvious?

Did have a quick browse about meta but couldn't see anything specific to this scenario.

Comment: New users **can** answer their own question, just fine.

Comment: And this is a duplicate, as soon as I can figure out the right search terms. You generally ask the OP to post the answer in a separate answer post, and if they don't respond, do so yourself as a Community Wiki post (to avoid being called a rep hunter), removing the answer from the question itself.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Depending on their privileges they may not be able to answer for the first few hours after asking. I don't know the exact details, but that may be what is prompting them to answer in edits instead. The only time when you can self-answer regardless of your privileges is if you post it together with your question.

Comment: See also: [Answers embedded in questions by low rep users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197710)

Comment: I am aware of the delay, but the treatment is still the same :-)

Comment: I always just edit the answer out and copy it into a community wiki answer

Comment: You should rollback such an edit which self answers the question. Have a [look here]( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201874/editing-the-question-such-that-it-answers-itself).

Comment: yep, does does appear to be a duplicate! @AlEverett