# Whether making changes from one of the answer is fine?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently i asked [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224887/questions-changed-on-getting-answer-to-current-question). there i got to know that if question is changed completely then a person with edit privilege can roll back the question to old one.
Now my question is suppose a partial answer is given (of significance) then the OP makes changes from my answer to his code and waits for rest part of his solution. this makes my answer look irrelevant since already the changes that my answer suggested are reflected in question. so what can be done?

Comment: Partially or fully, the question must not be edited to include anything from the answers provided to it. Only formatting and extra relevant code can be added if it makes the question more clearer.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ ok. can anyone roll back question? or we should comment and ask the OP to roll back the question to previous state?

Comment: It would be better to post a comment asking the OP to do that. That serves 2 purposes - first, the question is reverted back and second, the OP now knows what was done was wrong and won't repeat it in the future. If possible, [post a link to one of the meta questions which talk about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201874/216721) so that the OP can know more.